# Pulling data from a server causes memory warning

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am working on an IOS application. This application connects a server and gets all rows of each table. Some code of my app is below;

```
for(NSString* tableName in dtTables)
{
    long PageCount=2000;

    long rowCount=0;
    long currCount=0;

    .
    .

    rowCount= [(NSNumber*)[row objectAtIndex:0] longValue];  // count row in the table

     while (currCount<rowCount)
     {

        long Next=MIN(PageCount,rowCount-currCount);

        SkylightQuery* query = [ServerQueryGenerator GenerateSelect:tableName :nil :nil :nil :nil :false :nil];
        query.LimitBegin=currCount;
        query.LimitLenght= Next;

        NSMutableDictionary* table = [[ServerDatabase SI] Select:query];

        .
        .
        currCount +=Next;
      } // while
}//for
```

In `Select` method of `ServerDatabase` class, I send request within serizalized Skylight query variable to server. `Command` variable holds a string that contains serialized server request.

```
NSURLRequest *Request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[command stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
NSURLResponse *Response = nil;
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: Request returningResponse: &Response error: &err];
```

There are 70 table in server. Some tables have 100 record and some tables have 10000 record.
So I am getting datas in each table 2000 by 2000.

There are two problem I faced here .

1. After getting some table data(5000 rows tables etc.) program causes memorv warning several times and exit .
2. Getting 2000 rows of a table from server is too slow. Sometimes It takes 1 minute.

How can I manage or solve these problems?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to find a way to retrieve only a subset of matching entries from your query (from which you can retrieve additional matches as the user scrolls or pulls to refresh in the table).  Do you (or a database administrator) have a way to put that API or functionality into place for your iOS app to use?

Comment: For working offline, I need to pull all database from server and I need to use a .net server get tables and contents because of security and restrictions. No API for my app unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it generates an SQL select statement so you should be setting some limits to filter (or paginate) the data that you are retrieving. You can still gather all of the data if you need it. You don't show how you're handling the response data but it should generally be stored to disk before you start the next download(s).

Comment: I am deserializing response data and storing it in local database using sqlite3. I am using also limits to reduce data amount.(2000 row in each request)

Comment: If you get memory warnings then 2000 is too big or you aren't processing the data properly. Use Instruments to find out which.

Comment: Which suggests the 2000 is too big. Do some experiments with smaller row counts and try Instruments.

Comment: Ok. I will try smaller counts.